# Review of a C++ missing characters snippet

Tags: c++

I recently had to write a function to return characters missing from an input string.  Here is the snippet

```
#include <bitset>
#include <string>

template<class Iterator>
std::string getMissingLetters(Iterator begin, Iterator end) {

    std::bitset<26> letters;

    for (auto it = begin; it != end; ++it) {
        size_t c = tolower(*it) - char('a'); // normalized to start at 'a'
        if (c > 26) continue;
        letters.set(c);
        if (letters.to_ulong() == ((1 << 26) - 1)) break;  // all 26 bits set
    }

    std::string missing;
    for (int i = 0; i < letters.size(); ++i) {
        if (!letters[i]) missing.push_back(char('a' + i));
    }
    return missing;
}
```

I thought of couple things to improve, for example avoiding branch by clamping characters, eg.

```
letters.set(std::min(c, 26));
```

and perhaps blocking the loop s.t. the line

```
if (letters.to_ulong() == ((1 << 26) - 1)) break;
```

is executed every N iterations rather than each iteration.

What do you think one could have done better?

Comment: I'd use `std::size_t` specifically, especially in the second `for`-loop.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of starting from a zero-ed bitset and then set them to `true` one by one, you could start with all `true`, set to `false` one by one and then use `std::bitset::none()` to break the loop.

But, apart from this small thing, `std::string` will probably preallocate memory (on the heap or on the stack; it's implementation dependent), whether or not you add a letter.  My advice would be to use an `std::array` with a fixed size of 26 (or your own stack implementation of a string) to directly store the letters, and remove the bitset and `std::string`.

That should simplified the code.  As the 26 `char`s will be stored in 7 `int`, copying or overwriting that size from the stack should be blazing fast (the cache lines of a modern processor is 32 bytes) compared to multiple math operations and a potential heap allocation.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use:

```
std::bitset<26> letters_r ((1 << 26)-1);
...
for (it = begin; it != end; ++it) {
    ...
    letters_r.reset(c);
    if (letters_r.to_ulong() == 0 ) break;  // all 26 bits reset
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bug, should be:

```
if (c >= 26) continue;
```

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted. It could have (maybe) used a tiny bit of explanation, but yes, `'z' - 'a' == 25` (`'(' - 'a' == 26`), and calling `set(26)` on a bitset of size 26 is rather bad.

Comment: @Corbin: It wasn't me, but I do agree that this should've been explained.